# Conectar PHP con Java

Tags: java, php, android

Estoy haciendo una aplicación, tengo una base de datos en *Hostinger* ya creada y los archivos *PHP* conectados también para que me coja las columnas correspondientes. Mi problema es que no sé cómo conectar estos *PHP* con el *Java*. ¿Cómo hago la conexión? Lo que quiero es mostrar simplemente la query, pues es una aplicación de prueba.

**db_connector.php**

```
<?php
define('DB_USER', "****"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', "****"); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "****"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "mysql.hostinger.es"); // db server?>
```

**db_config.php**

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
// import database connection variables
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

// get all columns from Preguntes table
$result = mysqli_query($db->connect(),"SELECT * FROM Preguntes") or        die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results

    $response["test"] = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $test = array();
        $test["ID"] = $row["ID"];
        $test["Pregunta"] = $row["Pregunta"];
        $test["Respostes"] = $row["Respostes"];
        $test["Image"] = $row["Image"];

        // push test into final response array
        array_push($response["test"], $test);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}   else {
    // query is empty
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Query is empty";

    // echo no query JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}?>
```

**database.php**

```
/**
* A class file to connect to database
*/

require_once 'db_config.php';
class DB_CONNECT {

    // connexion property
    private $con = NULL;
    private $db_server;
    private $db_user;
    private $db_password;
    private $db_database;

    // constructor
    function __construct($db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_database) {
        $this->db_server = $db_server;
        $this->db_user = $db_user;
        $this->db_password = $db_password;
        $this->db_database = $db_database;
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }
    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }
    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        if($this->con==NULL) {
            // Connecting to mysql database
            $this->con = mysqli_connect($this->db_server, $this->db_user, $this->db_password, $this->db_database) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        // returing connection cursor
        return $this->con;
    }
    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close() {
        if($this->con!=NULL) {
            // closing db connection
            mysqli_close($this->con);
        }
    }
}?>
```

Comment: No queda claro como quieres "conectar php con Java", menos que eso tiene que ver con android o android studio.

Comment: quiero en el java hacer la query para que me coja los datos de la base de datos de hostinger

Comment: Entonces te quieres conectarte desde una app en Android a la base de datos que accedes con el codigo en php arriba, cierto?

Comment: Quieres obtener los datos que genera tu PHP en tu aplicación Android?

Comment: Si! Eso es, quiero acceder a los datos que genera el php

Comment: Como relaciono esto con
 makeJsonRequest("**".php);
 makeImageRequest("**.jpg");

Cómo le indico mis documentos??

Comment: No sería mas fácil conectar a la base de datos directamente usando Java ahorrándote pasar por el php de conexión?

Answer (score 1):

Veo que tu interfaz de comunicación con el server es mediante respuestas codificadas en JSON, sin embargo sería más fácil si implementaras al menos un API tipo *REST* sencillo, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
<?php  
header("Content-Type: application/JSON; charset=utf-8");  
const DB_SERVER = 'localhost';  
const DB_USER = 'user';  
const DB_PASS = 'password';  
const DB_NAME = 'database';  
$db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

switch($method) {  
    case 'GET':  
            // todas tus interacciones basadas en solicitudes normales de tipo GET, por ejemplo:  
            if($_GET['action'] == 'preguntas') {  
                // consulta para devolver todas las preguntas...  
                $consulta = $db-query('SELECT * FROM preguntas');  
                .....  
                // la consulta fue exitosa  
                $db->close();  
                http_response_code(200);  
                print json_encode($consulta, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);  
            }......  
            break;  
        case 'POST':  
            // ahora acá todas tus acciones para las solicitudes tipo POST  
            break;  
        case 'PUT':  
            // acá todo lo de las consultas tipo PUT  
            break;  
        case 'DELETE':  
            // y acá todo lo de DELETE  
            break;  
        default:  
            // acá lo que pasará si ningún tipo de método concuerda aunque es raro que pase  
            break;  
}
```

Para las URL amigables puedes usar un archivo `.htaccess` para que de esta forma puedas hacer las peticiones con una URL estilo `http://tu-sitio.com/preguntas/` para que al hacer la petición `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` o `DELETE` a esa misma URL puedas realizar diferentes acciones relacionadas con las preguntas.
El `.htaccess` debería de verse algo así:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]*)/$ api.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]*)/([0-9]+) api.php?action=$1&question_id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Luego desde tu app Android podrías ayudarte de librerías buenísimas para consultas asíncronas como `Volley` que pertenece a Google y es gratuita, solo agrega la dependencia a tu gradle:

> `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'`

También puede serte de utilidad `Gson` que sirve para parsear tus JSON a diferentes tipos de objetos Java, desde `String` hasta tus propias clases personalizadas:

> `complile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'`

Este **[ejemplo](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/05/crear-un-webservice-para-android-con-mysql-php-y-json/)** puede ser de tu utilidad

Con esto en tus `Activity`, `Fragment`, `Services`, o practicamente donde sea puedes hacer consultas a tu servidor con `Volley` aunque te recomiendo que lo implementes en un `Singleton` para que puedas acceder a el sin necesidad de estar pasando entre actividades la instancia del `Volley`. Esto igual puedes ver como se hace en la web que te dejé arriba.
Igual te recomiendo que utilices una clase única y exclusivamente para almacenar tus construcciones para las URL amigables para tu *API REST*, algo como esto:

```
public class Constantes {  
    public static final String URL_PRINCIPAL = "http://tu-sitio.com/";  
    public static final String GET_TODAS_PREGUNTAS = URL_PRINCIPAL + "preguntas/";  
    public static final String POST_RESPUESTAS = URL_PRINCIPAL + "respuestas/";  
}
```

Así basta conque en cualquier parte de tu código hagas:

```
Constantes.GET_TODAS_PREGUNTAS  
    ....
```

Para referirse a la URL formada para la consulta a tu *API REST*.

Answer (score 0):

La solución en general sería montar un "servicio", uses PHP o cualquier tencnología para el backend de lo que estás montando. Desde Android o cualquier otro sistema puedes llamar al servicio, pasándole parámetros si hace falta y obtendrás la respuesta.

Lo más sencillo que puedes hacer es una página en PHP que devuelva en texto sencillo, llamas desde Android a esa página y procesas el texto. Si el texto que devuelves es en JSON puedes parsearlo luego en Java fácilmente con la librería Jackson por ejemplo (si en vez de JSON usas otra solución que también sea fácilmente parseable en Java, te vale igualmente).

Pero esto sería una solución sencilla, si vas a montar algo serio profundiza en cómo montar servicios web en PHP para contemplar detalles de seguridad y lo que te haga falta.

Answer (score 0):

tal vez esto te sirva, tomar en cuenta que la libreria esta depreciada , tambien tomar en cuenta que esto se deberia ejecutar con una tarea asincronica

```
    //Creamos un ArrayList para enviar los parametros en caso de que existan

    String respuesta="error";
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postparameters2send = new ArrayList<>();

    postparameters2send.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usuario", username));
    postparameters2send.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    //la url de nuestro php
    String URL_connect = "www.mysitioweb.com\acceso.php";

    //realizamos una peticion y como respuesta obtenes un array JSON
    JSONArray jdata = post.getserverdata(postparameters2send, URL_connect);


    //si lo que obtuvimos no es null
    if (jdata != null && jdata.length() > 0) {

        return jdata.toString();

    } else{
        return "error";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te ayudará [Php Java bridge pachage](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/).

[image: Así es como funciona]